# Using group_by() similarly as filter() in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

On the sample `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 3, 4, NA, NA, 6, 9, NA, 10),
V2 = seq(1:9))
```

Using `group_by()` in the fashion of `filter()` gives these results:

```
df %>%
  group_by(miss = !is.na(V1)) %>%
  mutate(lag = V1 - lag(V1))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   miss [2]
     V1    V2 miss    lag
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <dbl>
1    1.    1. TRUE    NA 
2    3.    2. TRUE     2.
3    4.    3. TRUE     1.
4   NA     4. FALSE   NA 
5   NA     5. FALSE   NA 
6    6.    6. TRUE     2.
7    9.    7. TRUE     3.
8   NA     8. FALSE   NA 
9   10.    9. TRUE     1.
```

It is exactly what I wanted but I'm curious whether it is intended to use `group_by()` also this way.

Comment: That's pretty interesting! I guess it's creating a new variable and grouping by it in as single step?

Comment: This is documented, there is an example under `?group_by` where it describes how you can group by expressions.

Comment: @joran you are right. I missed it.

Comment: fyi, my comment wasn't meant in an accusatory sense ("Read the docs!"), I just read your question and was like, I feel like I've seen this mentioned before but I had also forgotten about it, and then scrolled through the examples.

Comment: @joran Of course, I didn't take it as an insult. I'm glad you provided the answer to this question :)

Comment: I wouldn't say using `group_by` this way resembles `filter`, since `filter` removes false rows. It's more like using `ifelse` or `case_when` in `mutate`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of having a documented answer to this interesting question - from the comments, as @Joran has pointed out, `group_by` can be used with expressions. as @avid_useR pointed out, it does not really resemble `filter`, but more something like `case_when`, because no rows are removed.

Comment: closer to if_else(cond, TRUE, FALSE) rather than case_when